# Globally accessible variables in Matlab (something like #define in C, not 'global')

Tags: matlab

**I need to make a few constants accessible to my whole program (including classes).** In C, I would put some `#define`s into a header file, and include it where I need the variables. Unfortunately, I do not see a way to do this in Matlab. Variables defined as `global` are **not** visible in classes.

So how can I do this?

```
globVar = someValue; // define globVar somewhere, somehow


classdef MyClass
   // want to access globVar here
end
```

(I'm aware that global variables are bad design in many cases, but here they would be useful: It's about storing a list of commands of a communication protocoll.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will a class containing constant properties work in your case?

Here is example:

```
classdef Constants

    properties (Constant)        
        pi_ =  pi ;
        golden_ =  (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2  ;       
    end
end
```

You can access pi_ and golden_ anywhere in matlab code like this:

```
Constants.pi_ 
Constants.golden_
```